# How to use the variable inside the foreach loop in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8

This is my actual for-each loop.I need to convert that into java8 for loop.

```
for (PromotionEntity promotionEntity : pestudents) {
                List<ClassAttendanceChild> attendancelist = session.createQuery("from ClassAttendanceChild where attendanceadded='" + day + "' and pid.pId='" + promotionEntity.getpId() + "'").list();
                if (!attendancelist.isEmpty()) {
                    ClassAttendanceChild attendenceDetails = (ClassAttendanceChild) attendancelist.get(0);
                    if (attendenceDetails.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        present++;
                        System.out.println("present = " + present);
                    } else {
                        Absent++;
                        System.out.println("Absent = " + Absent);
                    }
                } else {
                    nottaken++;
                    System.out.println("nottaken = " + nottaken);
                }
            }
```

How to convert that to java8 for loop,I am getting exceptions in that variable increment:

```
 pestudents.forEach(promotionEntity -> {
            List<ClassAttendanceChild> attendancelist = session.createQuery("from ClassAttendanceChild where attendanceadded='" + day + "' and pid.pId='" + promotionEntity.getpId() + "'").list();
            if (!attendancelist.isEmpty()) {
                 ClassAttendanceChild attendenceDetails = (ClassAttendanceChild) attendancelist.get(0);
                  if (attendenceDetails.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
//                    present++;
//                    System.out.println("present = " + present);
                } else {
//                    Absent++;
//                    System.out.println("Absent = " + Absent);
                }
            } else {
//                nottaken++;
//                System.out.println("nottaken = " + nottaken);
            }


        });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the code?  It will be much more complicated and possibly slower in your case, unless you intend to make it parallel.

Comment: how to make that in parallel?

Comment: Add `.parallelStream()` and make it thread safe.

Comment: Is to possible to show me a smale example for my above code

Answer (score 4):

As usual, when you decide to go functional, you must step back to a higher-level description of what you are aiming for, and then rewrite your code in FP style.

You want to determine the total count for three categories of events: "present", "absent", and "nottaken". Here is a suggestion on how to achieve it the FP-way (thanks to Stuart Marks for pointing out how to construct a library-provided frequency-counting collector):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

...

System.out.println(pestudents.stream().collect(groupingBy(pe -> {
    final List<ClassAttendanceChild> attendancelist = session.createQuery(
        "from ClassAttendanceChild where attendanceadded='" + day 
        + "' and pid.pId='" + promotionEntity.getpId() + "'")
      .list();
    return attendancelist.isEmpty()? "nottaken"
        : attendancelist.get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")?
            "present" : "absent";
  }, counting())));
```

You can notice that we have split the work into two stages: first we classify each `PromotionEntity`, then perform the frequency-counting reduction on those. The outcome is a mapping from category to its count.

For me, clarity of intent is enough of an advantage of the FP style, but this has the additional advantage of preparing the terrain for parallelization. In this particular case parallelization would probably not pay off because the bottleneck is the database, but generally, if FP style is adopted throughout, paralellization becomes a much closer target.

---

#### (Original code, with custom collector)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final List<PromotionEntity> pestudents = ...your initialization...
  final Map<String, Integer> freqs = pestudents.stream().map(pe -> {
    final List<ClassAttendanceChild> attendancelist = session.createQuery(
           "from ClassAttendanceChild where attendanceadded='" + day + 
           "' and pid.pId='" + promotionEntity.getpId() + "'")
      .list();
    return attendancelist.isEmpty()? "nottaken" 
        : attendancelist.get(0).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")?
            "present" : "absent";
  }).collect(toFrequencyMap());
  System.out.println(freqs);
}

static Integer zeroForNull(Integer i) { return i == null? 0 : i; }

static <K> Collector<K, Map<K, Integer>, Map<K, Integer>> toFrequencyMap() {
  return Collector.of(
      HashMap<K, Integer>::new,
      (acc, key) -> acc.compute(key, (x, count) -> zeroForNull(count) + 1),
      (acc, source) -> {
        source.forEach((key, sourceCount) ->
          acc.compute(key, (x,accCount) ->
            sourceCount + zeroForNull(accCount)));
        return acc;
      },
      Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

Comment: +1 This could also use `parallelStream()` potentially.

Comment: Actually, since the Hibernate Session is involved, paralellization will be tricky. One would need a session per thread and a ThreadLocal store to keep the thread-bound sessions.

Comment: could anyone please explain me,How that above code is going to work because i am not understating that please.

Comment: How i can get the last output of absent,present and pending.

Comment: .collect(
    HashMap<String,Integer>::new,
    (acc, category) -> acc.compute(category, (x, count) -> zeroForNull(count) + 1),
    (target, source) -> source.forEach((category, sourceCount) ->
                          target.compute(category, (x,targetCount) ->
                            sourceCount + zeroForNull(targetCount))));

...

static Integer zeroForNull(Integer i) { return i == null? 0 : i; }

Comment: @user3415045 `System.out.println(freqs);` is one simple approach; also `freqs.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(v+" students were classified as "+k));`

Comment: @user3415045 I suppose you'll have to study the API for `Stream::collect` as a first step. Here the collect operation assembles the frequency map by incrementing the map value each time a certain key is encountered in the stream.

Comment: +1 for suggesting breaking down the problem into classification and frequency counting. There are pre-built collectors for these operations in the `Collectors` class. Consider `collect(groupingBy(classifierFunc, counting()))`.

Comment: @StuartMarks This is great: I did actually expect to find this in the library, but I didn't know `gropingBy` can be further composed with another collector!

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to modify local variables defined outside of the method passed to `forEach`. They must be declared `final` or at least be *effectively final*, meaning that they are never changed after their initialization.

What you could do is to change `present` and the other local variables into instance variables or class variables, those you are allowed to modify.

That said, I would recommend you to keep the old syntax, it is much more suited for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To parallelise this code you can use AtomicInteger as your thread safe counter.

```
AtomicInteger present = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger absent = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger nottaken = new AtomicInteger();

pestudents.parallelStream().forEach(promotionEntity -> {
        List<ClassAttendanceChild> attendancelist = session.createQuery("from ClassAttendanceChild where attendanceadded='" + day + "' and pid.pId='" + promotionEntity.getpId() + "'").list();
        if (!attendancelist.isEmpty()) {
             ClassAttendanceChild attendenceDetails = (ClassAttendanceChild) attendancelist.get(0);
              if (attendenceDetails.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                  present.incrementAndGet();
                  System.out.println("present = " + present);
            } else {
                  absent.incrementAndGet();
                  System.out.println("Absent = " + Absent);
            }
        } else {
              nottaken.incrementAndGet();
              System.out.println("nottaken = " + nottaken);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `Atomic` family of objects are thread-safe but they can give rise to contention problems if they're incremented often from multiple threads. Better alternatives for accumulation like this are `LongAdder` and `LongAccumulator` and corresponding `Double` classes (all in `java.util.concurrent.atomic`) which are designed for multi-threaded update and infrequent reads.

Comment: @StuartMarks I think you should consider context here.  The String concatenation will be much slower, the writing to the console will be much slower than that, and finally the hibernate query to the database will make everything else look trivial.  LongAdder might make more sense if it is clearer, rather than for performance reasons.

Comment: Right, for this case contention is unlikely to be an issue, the most prominent reason being that Hibernate sessions are typically not thread safe! Aside from the specifics here the general pattern of accumulating within a parallel stream is better served by LongAdder et al since they are designed to avoid contention over updates. Their APIs are similar in complexity to the Atomic family.